# How to define an `Index()` in SqlAlchemy+Alembic, on a column from a base table

Tags: python, inheritance, indexing, sqlalchemy, alembic

I am a python novice.

My project is using SqlAlchemy, Alembic and MyPy.

I have a pair of parent-child classes defined like this (a bunch of detail elided):

```
class RawEmergency(InputBase, RawTables):
    __tablename__ = "emergency"

    id: Mapped[UNIQUEIDENTIFIER] = mapped_column(
        UNIQUEIDENTIFIER(), primary_key=True, autoincrement=False
    )

    attendance_id: Mapped[str | None] = guid_column()
    admitted_spell_id: Mapped[str | None] = guid_column()


    __table_args__ = (
        PrimaryKeyConstraint("id", mssql_clustered=False),
        Index(
            "index_emergency_pii_patient_id_and_datetimes",
            pii_patient_id,
            attendance_start_date.desc(),
            attendance_start_time.desc(),
        ),
    )

class InputBase(DeclarativeBase):
    metadata = MetaData(schema="raw")

    refresh_date: Mapped[str] = date_str_column()
    refresh_time: Mapped[str] = time_str_column()

class RawTables(object):
    id: Mapped[UNIQUEIDENTIFIER] = mapped_column(
        UNIQUEIDENTIFIER(), primary_key=True, autoincrement=False
    )

    __table_args__: typing.Any = (
        PrimaryKeyConstraint(name="id", mssql_clustered=False),
    )
```

I want to add a 2nd index to the Emergency table, indexing the refresh columns provided by the base table.

I expect to do so by adding an additional `Index()` call into the `__table_args__` setup.

Then I want to run my standard migration creation/checking tool:
`poetry run alembic --config operator_app/alembic.ini revision --autogenerate -m "refresh_col_indexes"`

How do I reference the refresh columns in this declaration?

---

Current <s>attem</s>guesses that have failed:

```
    Index(
        "index_emergency_refresh_date_time",
        refresh_date.desc(),
        refresh_time.desc(),
    ),
```

mypy and the IDE both say they don't know what `refresh_date` is.
`error: Name "refresh_date" is not defined  [name-defined]`

```
    Index(
        "index_emergency_refresh_date_time",
        InputBase.refresh_date.desc(),
        InputBase.refresh_time.desc(),
    ),
```

compiles now, but the alembic command doesn't work:
`sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Can't add unnamed column to column collection full error below`

```
    Index(
        "index_emergency_refresh_date_time",
        super().refresh_date.desc(),
        super().refresh_time.desc(),
    ),
```

Mypy/IDE say no:
`error: "super()" outside of a method is not supported`

```
    Index(
        "index_emergency_refresh_date_time",
        super(InputBase, self).refresh_date.desc(),
        super(InputBase, self).refresh_time.desc(),
    ),
```

`self is not defined`

```
    Index(
        "index_emergency_refresh_date_time",
        super(InputBase, None).refresh_date.desc(),
        super(InputBase, None).refresh_time.desc(),
    ),
```

mypy says `Unsupported argument 2 for "super"`
and alembic says `AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'refresh_date'`

Comment: Hello. I'm trying to reproduce this. How are the `date_str_column`, `guid_column` `time_str_column` functions defined? Also can you provide information on`RawTables`?

Comment: Ah, sorry. They're just trivial commonisation of the VARCHAR length

Comment: `return mapped_column(String(10))` and `16` for time.

Comment: `RawTables` added.

Comment: @Brondahl any reason my suggestion does not work for you? noticed you replied to the comments, was wondering if there is anything I could modify so that it is better

Comment: Nope, I hadn't gotten to trying and testing it yet :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sqlalchemy.orm.declared_attr` for this. You can add any number of index you want under `__table_args__`

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Index
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped, mapped_column, DeclarativeBase, declared_attr


class InputBase(DeclarativeBase):
    refresh_date: Mapped[str]
    refresh_time: Mapped[str]


class RawEmergency(InputBase):
    __tablename__ = "emergency"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)

    attendance_id: Mapped[str | None]
    admitted_spell_id: Mapped[str | None]

    @declared_attr
    def __table_args__(cls):
        return (
            Index(
                "index_emergency_refresh_date_time",
                cls.refresh_date.desc(),
                cls.refresh_time.desc(),
            ),
        )

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///temp.sqlite", echo=True)
InputBase.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

These are the queries emitted.

```
CREATE TABLE emergency (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
        attendance_id VARCHAR, 
        admitted_spell_id VARCHAR, 
        refresh_date VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
        refresh_time VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

sqlalchemy.engine.Engine CREATE INDEX index_emergency_refresh_date_time ON emergency (refresh_date DESC, refresh_time DESC)
```

Comment: Yup, that works perfectly. And feels nicer than the other alternative that a collegue offered (see other answer)

Comment: Are there any subtle differences that I should know about, between this definition of `__table_args__` (function with `@declared_attr` and `self`) and the original property?

Comment: Particualrly in the context of "all the other tables still use the old version

Comment: @Brondahl I made a semantic mistake, `declared_attr` is technically a classmethod `cls` instead of `self` (edited), as for differences, I am not entirely sure, but I usually understood and use this as a "dynamically generate attributes" feature

Comment: Ah ... still syntactically valid, because "self" isn't truly a keyword .. just the conventional name for that param? so in the original code, you just "mispelled" `cls`

Comment: yup, nothing functionally changed, if you were using a type checker I think it would have warned you @Brondahl (type checkers suggest you also annotate @classmethod) but sqlalchemy functionally does not need this, more info [here towards the end](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.declared_attr)

Answer (score 1):

Defining it entirely outside the class works, but feels less nice that @python_user's solution

```
class RawEmergency(InputBase, RawTables):
    __tablename__ = "emergency"

    id: Mapped[UNIQUEIDENTIFIER] = mapped_column(
        UNIQUEIDENTIFIER(), primary_key=True, autoincrement=False
    )

    attendance_id: Mapped[str | None] = guid_column()
    admitted_spell_id: Mapped[str | None] = guid_column()


    __table_args__ = (
        PrimaryKeyConstraint("id", mssql_clustered=False),
        Index(
            "index_emergency_pii_patient_id_and_datetimes",
            pii_patient_id,
            attendance_start_date.desc(),
            attendance_start_time.desc(),
        ),
    )

Index(
    "index_emergency_refresh_date_time",
    RawEmergency.__table__.c.refresh_date.desc(),
    RawEmergency.__table__.c.refresh_time.desc(),
)
```

Comment: camelCase username of mine triggers me :)

Comment: apologies, .NET dev here :D, but I should have gone and checked. Fixed.

Comment: I only mean that as a joke (python prefers snake_case and I noticed your comment), appreciate the edit nonetheless :)